# Closed regular neighborhood

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, knot-theory

I would like to understand the following sentences.

> Let $L$ be a framed link in the three dimensional sphere $S^3$. Suppose $L$ has $m$ components $L_1, \cdots, L_m$. Let $U$ be a **closed regular neighborhood** of $L$ in $S^3$.

Here what I do not understand is the definition of **closed regular neighborhood**. It seems that $U$ is solid tori whose cores are $L_i$'s.

I know such solid tori are some kind of neighborhoods, but why is it closed? In my understanding, "closed" means "compact and no boundary". But a solid torus has a boundary.

Also what is "regular" here?

I appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closed here means "closed in the sense of general topology". (You can also say "compact" if you prefer.)

Unfortunately, the words "closed", "interior" and "boundary" have different meaning in geometric topology and general topology and, moreover, this meaning is frequently mixed (e.g. the general topology meaning is used in geometric topology papers). Fortunately, it is (mostly) clear from the context which meaning is being used. (If something cannot be closed as a manifold then it is closed as a subset.)

Comment: Thank you. Could you also tell me what "regular" means?

Comment: @Snow: "Regular" is a concept from the PL topology: Let $D$ be a subcomplex of a simplicial complex $C$. Let $C''$ be the 2nd barycentric subdivision of $C$. Then the regular neighborhood of $D$ is the subcomplex consisting of all simplices of $C''$ which have nonempty intersection with $D''$. (It is "closed" by definition.) In your case, this just means a disjoint union of solid tori containing circles $L_i$ as core curves (as you correctly guessed).  People also use the name "tubular" neighborhood for this.

Comment: @Snow: There is also a differential topology interpretation of "regular neighborhood". For any differentiable manifold $M$ and any compact smooth submanifold $N$ with normal bundle $\nu(N)$, there exists a homeomorphism $\nu(N) \to U(N)$ onto an open neighborhood of $N$ which is the identity on the zero section. If you then pick a smoothly varying positive definite quadratic form on the fibers of $\nu(N)$, and define $\nu_1(N)$ to be all vectors of norm $\le 1$, the image of $\nu_1(N)$ in $U(N)$ is the "regular neighborhood" of $N$.